# Node.js cluster module doesn't release socket/port on http.Server.close()

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, phantomjs

In a Node.js script, I'm trying to open some ports/sockets and then close them again. I'm running into trouble when using Node.js Cluster module. It doesn't seem to close ports in the same way the same code does when not using the Cluster module.

For example, take the following code which creates 5 http.Server's each on it's own port and then closes all but the last (5th) one.

```js
'use strict';

var http = require('http');

function goGoGadget(i) {
    console.log('var i = ', i);

    var httpServer = http.createServer();
    var nextPort = 4000 + i;

    console.log('about to listen on port', nextPort);
    httpServer.listen(nextPort);

    if (i < 5) {
        httpServer.on('listening', function() {
            console.log('closing port:', nextPort);
            httpServer.close(function() {
                console.log('closed server on port:', nextPort);
            });
        });
    }
}

goGoGadget(1);
goGoGadget(2);
goGoGadget(3);
goGoGadget(4);
goGoGadget(5);
```

As expected, only one port remains opened by node.js:

```
dhcp50:test marco$ lsof -i -n -P | grep node
node      20895 marco   16u  IPv4 0xb242422d2e0e2bb1      0t0  TCP *:4005 (LISTEN)
```

Then, the same code but run in workers using the Cluster module:

```
'use strict';

var cluster = require('cluster');
var http = require('http');

function goGoGadget(i) {
    console.log('var i = ', i);

    var httpServer = http.createServer();
    var nextPort = 4000 + i;

    console.log('about to listen on port', nextPort);
    httpServer.listen(nextPort);

    if (i < 5) {
        httpServer.on('listening', function() {
            console.log('closing port:', nextPort);
            httpServer.close(function() {
                console.log('closed server on port:', nextPort);
            });
        });
    }
}

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    var numWorkers = 5;

    for (var i = 0; i < numWorkers; i += 1) {
        console.log ('forking ', i + 1);
        cluster.fork();
    }
}
else {
    goGoGadget(cluster.worker.id);
}
```

This time, Node.js keeps holding onto ports of the first 4 http.Server's, even though they've been closed:

```
dhcp50:test marco$ lsof -i -n -P | grep node
node      20900 marco   17u  IPv4 0xb242422d2d9682e1      0t0  TCP *:4004 (LISTEN)
node      20900 marco   18u  IPv4 0xb242422d2d5faa11      0t0  TCP *:4001 (LISTEN)
node      20900 marco   19u  IPv4 0xb242422d2d5fd621      0t0  TCP *:4005 (LISTEN)
node      20900 marco   20u  IPv4 0xb242422d2d985141      0t0  TCP *:4002 (LISTEN)
node      20900 marco   21u  IPv4 0xb242422d2d9862e1      0t0  TCP *:4003 (LISTEN)
node      20905 marco   13u  IPv4 0xb242422d2d5fd621      0t0  TCP *:4005 (LISTEN)
```

My question is simply: Why? and How do I get them to close? I have a suspicion that if I used the *exclusive* option in [net.Server.listen()](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listen_options_callback) the ports might close, but the [http.Server.listen()](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen_port_hostname_backlog_callback) API does not seem to take this options hash as an argument.

The genesis of this question comes from an issue when using phantom-node (with phantomjs) to open many number of pages over time in a Express.js app that uses the Cluster module. To make sure there's no port collision when creating a new phantom-node instance, and to avoid `EADDRINUSE`, I do a port-scan and check that the port i'm about to use is available. The issue becomes that, over time, more and more ports are opened and because they're never closed, node eventually crashes with an `EMFILE` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that, the issue described appears up through Node v0.11.1. From 0.11.2 sockets are successfully unlinked when closed. Fixed by [this commit](https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/41b75ca9263f368db790fbdcc3963bb1a8c5cb7e#comments).

Cool.

Answer (score 0):

What I have noticed is maybe a part of the answer for you : Sometimes, system doesn't release ports when asked to be closed. I had this issue with a little shell script closing forever (nodejs persistency module), pulling the new code from git and starting it again. The server would not start again because it said "port xxxx already in use".

Comment: That sounds like a different thing. *forever* probably kept restarting your script in conjunction with the script being run by you elsewhere, which might have resulted in two separate processes trying to listen on the same port, which would result in, as you said, `EADDRINUSE`. However, my question isn't about `EADDRINUSE`..

Comment: I see, the script that caused me "problems" was just doing "forever stop script", git pull, then forever start with all parameters for log files.